# a/the when talking about the company in a resume

Tags: grammar, resume

In a resume, where the format is:

```
{Company Name} - {Title} - {Start Date} - {End Date} - {Location}
{Summary of the responsibilities and accomplishments at the company}
```

One of the entries is the following:

```
ABC, Inc. - Co-Founder - June 2020 - Present - Los Angeles, CA
Founded the company producing state of the art electron microscopes. <Continues with other stuff>
```

One person reviewing my resume commented that "the" cannot be used in "Founded the company" and should be reworded to something like "Founded a company ...", because "the" was not referring to any previous sentence.

But I'm thinking the exact opposite. To me, using "a" makes it more vague as it stresses that I founded ***a*** company and not necessarily ABC Inc. I think "the" is perfectly addressing the company in the header, directly one line above it.

However being non-native, I wanted to get a second opinion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both work in this sense, and to my mind I would prefer yours over your friends.  That said, neither is exactly the best way to phrase the sentence.   Consider:

> Co-Founded of (Company Namy) and (what did you bring to the table as a founder of the company with your fellow founders?).  Lead the formation of our primary business offering of state-of-the-art electron microscopes. [Continues with other stuff].

This will eliminate your debate with your buddy, shares the credit with your co-founder(s) and puts an emphasis on your leadership skills and entrepreneurial abilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's a good alternative. At the time of writing, I felt like repeating the company name in both lines didn't look good.

Comment: @Sam NP.   I would use whatever official title you used to describe your work role (Lead designer?  CEO?  CFO? Marketing.) in addition to being the founder.